# Fallback for SVG fill image source

Tags: ios, css, svg, fill, fallback

I am looking into using an image as an SVG fill. I am currently using the following SVG markup:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="logo" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 25" enable-background="new 0 0 0 0" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <pattern id="bg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="300" height="25">
        <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="..." preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<g class="graphic">
    <path d="..."></path>
</g>
```

*(I have left some details out ("...") of which I am sure are not relevant to my issue.)*

In CSS, I use the following code to append the pattern ID. Pls see below:

```
.default-header .site-name svg.logo .graphic {
    fill:url(#bg);
}
```

I've already done some digging and found out that this technique (images as SVG background) isn't supported in FireFox and iOS Safari. Therefore I used the following "fall-back" method in CSS:

```
.default-header .site-name svg.logo .graphic {
    fill:#ddd;
}

@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {

    .default-header .site-name svg.logo .graphic {
        fill:url(#bg);
    }
}
```

The above code works, EXCEPT for iOS 8/9's Safari. So my issue is mainly that I don't know how to target those non-supporting browsers, which I'm sure there are more of than I am currently testing. SO... I decided to use Modernizr to look for support, but I can't seeem to find an appropriate, representational way of checking if this SVG technique is supported. In other words, on this page: https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses, I can't find the browser feature appropriate for my issue.

I hope somebody knows what direction I could best look into or better yet, has some experience with this technique, which I still think is so awesome (if it works).

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Images as SVG background have been supported in Firefox since version 4 i.e since 2011. Where have you got your research from?

Comment: @RobertLongson It's not specifically a background, as in a property. It's a **fill**. This doesn't seem to work in FireFox, as far as I can tell. So no research, just personal experience.

Comment: It certainly does work in a fill provided you get the syntax right. I'm not really sure where you're going wrong with snippets you've provided. A [mcve] would help.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for your advice so far. Could you perhaps point out which type of "browser feature" at Modernizr would be representational for this type of thing? I personally don't like CSS hacks that much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using a different approach in markup. Instead of using defs and gs, I used the following markup to achieve the same effect:

```
<svg id="graphic" width="300" height="40">
    <!-- Graphic: Styling (inline as FF fix) -->
    <style> svg image { clip-path:url(#clipping); } </style>
    <!-- Clip Path -->
    <clipPath id="clipping">
        <!-- this might as well be any type of path -->
        <text id="graphicText" x="0" y="37">My Text</text>
    </clipPath>
    <!-- Image -->
    <image id="graphicImage" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{img_url}" width="300" height="300" x="0" y="-120px"></image>
</svg>
```

I used CSS styling for the text itself.

Hope this helps someone!